# Transcriptions of Mandarin Chinese into writing systems other than Latin, Arabic and Cyrillic?

Tags: chinese, writing-systems, tone, mandarin

I was wondering if Standard Chinese has been transliterated (either officially or unofficially) into writing systems other than the Latin (Pinyin, Wade-Giles), Arabic ([Xiao'erjing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiao%27erjing)) or Cyrillic ([Dungan Dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillization_of_Chinese)).

I am thinking of writing systems such as Japanese Kana, Devnagri, Thai, Burmese, Mongolian, Tibetan, Greek, and Latin with Romance pronounciation.

If possible, please provide examples. How do these systems denote phonemic aspects such as dipthongs, endings and tone?

Comment: The 'Phags-pa script was based on the Tibetan alphabet and was used officially for writing Chinese in the Yuan dynasty period. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27Phags-pa_script

Answer (score 1):

I found a paper from 2002 ("[*j-pinyin*: A New Systematic Approach to the Japanese Transcription of Chinese Syllables](http://www2.teu.ac.jp/kougi/hp037/paper/conf_paper/EAFTerm02.pdf)," by Jin-Hua SHE, Shumei CHEN, Sumio OHNO and Hiroyuki KAMEDA) that says that at that time, there was no general standard for transcribing modern Chinese into Japanese; it proposes the titular system which you can see described in the paper. I don't know if it's caught on at all.

It doesn't look like it transcribes tone. Diphthongs are just transcribed by using multiple kana. Apparently, in j-pinyin the difference between the coda consonants "n" and "ng" is represented by using a long vowel mark (ー) before the second.